# How to test python on Centos

Tags: centos, python

I have followed this tutorial and successfully did everything.

http://binarysushi.com/blog/2009/aug/19/CentOS-5-3-python-2-5-virtualevn-mod-wsgi-and-mod-rpaf/

how can i check that i everything is working.

I mean which page should i go to test

Answer (score 0):

Configure httpd to serve [this script](http://hg.moinmo.in/moin/1.8/raw-file/tip/wiki/server/test.wsgi), then go to its location.

Comment: Actually this is my production server where my cpanel/whm/php sites are hosted. Now i have use mydomian.com in the config file. I have entered the naeservers of my vps hosting . I am confused how will my new domain find that Vhost path. DO i need to create a new account via cpanel for that domain to work

Comment: Did you read the mod_wsgi configuration documentation?

Comment: I will check that, i forgot that